# Check the occurence of a group of items in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary

This is an example of data I work with it :

```
dictionary_of_elements = {'key1': ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a"],
                          'key2' : ["d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "d", "d"]}
```

The situation is :

I want to put a check while looping on this dictionnary to avoid the case where we write "a" in example 1 or "d" in the same key more than once.

I collect data from a handmade excel sheet so errors like this can happen.
Data is not orderned by alphabetical order so I cannot order them.

I though about parsing each list of each key in this dictionnary and creat and sub-list with this elements and then check on orignal list to see if there is still item "a" or "d".

Does anyone have a better suggestion ?

Correct output should be :

```
dictionary_of_elements = {'key1': ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"], 
                          'key2': ["d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e"]}
```

What I want to acheive is read data and check if there is error and inform user there is an error in his data.

There is no output to deliver other than a warning message and check again on data after that.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Use a `set` so duplicates can't happen to begin with? Use a `Counter` object? there are plenty of ways to check for duplicates, but you didn't provide any actual example

Comment: You forgot to post the code for your attempt at solving this.

Comment: Hello @DaniMesejo I have updated my question with more clarification

Comment: Hello @ScottHunter I could not put any code because there is not ! I'am looking for an idea that can point me to the right direction because 'set' and 'Counter' does not do the work for me

Comment: You say *avoid the case where we write "a" in example 1 or "d" in the same key more than once* and yet your *correct output"  has both of these very duplicates.

Comment: Hey @ScottHunter, I said more than once. It's okay to have duplicate but once we pass to another element in the same list we should not repeat another element that already exist that's why "a" and "d" exist but only in only one group

Comment: I think what you mean is that you don't want duplicated "runs" of keys (based on your expected output.  You need to re word the question because it is still not clear.  Do you mean "for each value in the dictionary (which is a list with implicit ordering), I want only one contiguous run of each value (e.g. once I have seen a run of `a` I do not want any further values `a`)."  This is what your desired output seems to indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to validate that the values are correct?

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to aggregate the consecutive keys, and check if there are any duplicated keys:

```
from itertools import groupby

valid_keys = {k: len(l:=[g for g,_ in groupby(v)]) == len(set(l))
              for k,v in dictionary_of_elements.items()}
```

a more efficient version with a classical loop:

```
valid_keys = {}

for k,v in dictionary_of_elements.items():
    seen = set()
    valid_keys[k] = True
    for g, _ in groupby(v):
        if g in seen:
            valid_keys[k] = False
            break
        seen.add(g)
```

output: `{'key1': False, 'key2': False}`

Comment: *"Data is not orderned by alphabetical order so I cannot order them"* So `itertools.groupby` might not work as expected, but:  I'm not sure why you opted to use it to begin with, and I'm not sure why OP "can't order them"

Comment: @DeepSpace that my precise point of using `groupby`, identifying non grouped duplicated keys, but it might be that I misunderstood the requirements. What I understood: `AAABBC` -> correct ; `AAABBCA` -> incorrect as `A` comes back a second time after a change.